# Regex, how to get a certain amount of lines of text up to a certain word with regex?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to pull the class and class number along with the prerequisites. However I am having trouble getting just the course (Ex: ACCT 203), up to and including the prerequisites (Ex: ACCT 301) and nothing else. I am doing this in python, in hopes of later inserting this data into a database. Can anyone help with this? I am relatively new to regex.

```
ACCT 203 
Financial Accounting Three Credits 
Development of basic accounting concepts. Emphasis is on the classifying, 
recording, and reporting of business transactions for all forms of business 
organizations. Offered every semester.
ACCT 204 
Managerial Accounting 
Three Credits
Emphasis is on generating, analyzing, and using accounting information in the 
planning and control processes. Topics include budgets, standards, cost systems, 
incremental analysis, and ~nancial statement analysis. Offered every semester. 
Prerequisite: 
ACCT 203
ACCT 301
Intermediate Accounting I 
Three Credits
This is the ~rst course in a two-course sequence that is intended to provide a 
comprehensive understanding of the concepts, principles, assumptions, and 
conventions that are used for classifying, recording, and reporting economic 
transactions for a business entity. Offered every fall. 
Prerequisite: 
ACCT 204 or permission of instructor
ACCT 302 
Intermediate Accounting II 
Three Credits
This is the second course in a two-course sequence that is intended to provide 
a comprehensive understanding of the concepts, principles, assumptions, and 
conventions that are used for classifying, recording, and reporting economic 
transactions for a business entity. Offered every spring. 
Prerequisite: 
ACCT 301 or permission of instructor
ACCT 303 
Accounting Theory and Practice 
Three Credits
This course is intended to provide an understanding of items that present 
measurement and reporting problems for the accountant. It will also discuss 
current issues that the accounting profession is attempting to establish and 
guidelines for their measurement and reporting. 
Prerequisite: 
ACCT 302
ACCT 310
```

Comment: Regex isn't that easy, not even for me (I'm already some years in Py programming). I recommend starting with some other topic...

Comment: Why do you believe that regular expressions are a solution?

Comment: I've tried ([A-Z]{3,4}\s\d\d\d)\D+[A-Z]{3,4} along with other basic ones like \D+\s\d\d\d @BAH

Comment: what other options are there? @cdarke

Comment: For example, `str.startswith('ACCT ')`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he will want to use this for more than just the accounting classes, though

Comment: How are  you retrieving this information?

Honestly I'd look into a more intelligent way of pulling the data, rather than finding a complicated way to parse a flat textfile

Comment: For example, if you're using a web crawler or something, maybe you could pull the data into a more readable format?

Comment: With what you describe, you do not need regex. Loop through the lines with `for inp_line in open('filename','r'):` and check if line contains what you are searching with `if 'ACCT 203' in inp_line:`.

Comment: Yeah, but there's other classes not just the Accounting, for example, after a certain part in the file it gets to be 'CMPT' @SciProg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is exactly what you want or not. But that's my solution for this;

```
>>> classes = re.findall("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][0-9]", text)  
>>> for i in classes:             #just find element by order
...     print(i)
...
ACCT 203
ACCT 204
ACCT 203
ACCT 301
ACCT 204
ACCT 302
ACCT 301
ACCT 303
ACCT 302
ACCT 310
```